# How do I push files specified in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-push, composer-php, phpfog

If I have a "vendors" directory in my .gitignore, is there a way I can set up a remote that will receive that directory anyway when I do a push?

Comment: "that will receive that directory anyway" - sorry, what do you mean? a directory is either ignored or not...

Comment: It may be that it's fundamentally not possible.  In which case, feel free to answer my question saying as much if you're positive of it :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're after. I've posted an answer with some possibilities from other SO Qs. If that's not quite what you're after, let us know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the functionality you're looking for can be achieved by having a branch used to deploy to your Cloud Provider.

Setup a `dev` branch which includes your `.gitignore` file, check your incremental work into that branch.

Merge your `dev` branch into your `deploy` branch which doesn't contain a `.gitignore` file but contains the vendors directory.

once you've completed your merge, push to the deployment remote from your `deploy` branch.

Comment: best solution for this I have heard recommended to date.  thanks

Answer (score 10):

Your `.gitignore` file has nothing to do with pushing.  It is used by things like `git status` and `git add` to figure out what files should be (or could be) part of a future commit.  You can add things that are ignored using the `git add` command; it will throw an error unless you use the `-f` option:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
somefilename
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Once you've added the file to the repository, it will be pushed along with any other changes.

Comment: Problem is, I don't want to commit this directory to my repo, I only want it to be included on a push to a specific remote (appfog).  In this case, it's a directory with automatically managed dependencies.

Comment: That's fine, but it is still the case that the `.gitignore` file does not control what gets pushed where.

Answer (score 2):

use `-f` to forcefully add.

Here is the example.

```
git add -f path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nishad-up](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4705929/nishad-up)'s answer is correct: `git commit` and `git push` will only handle the content you set to update to the remote. But when you call `git add` on something that's in .gitignore, or inside a folder that's listed there, git doesn't accept the command, and throws the error you got.
You have to force staging such files or folders using `git add -f relative-path-to/my-file.png` or whatever file(s) you want, the rest is the same (git commit, git push, etc).
*I couldn't figure out how to do this through the VS-Code source control bar, I had to do it in the terminal.