# Git: Is there anyway to push one file which is already added into gitignore?

Tags: git

I just want to push file without edit gitignore

i.e i added /vendor in gitignore. but i need to push one file which is available in /vendor/test.txt

i don't need to push other file except test.txt
how can i do that 
any idea please share

Comment: `/vendor` -> `/vendor/*`

Comment: You can just drop this line in .gitignore, add the file, then checkout the original .gitignore. This file is used to choose which previously untracked files should be ignored, but the files which are already tracked are not affected by it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push files specified in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788229/how-do-i-push-files-specified-in-gitignore)

Comment: Note that Git doesn't push *files*; `git push` pushes *commits*. Commits *have* files but the thing you're working with is not a file but rather a commit (or many commits). This eventually matters quite a lot, so it's wise to avoid using the phrase "push a file".

Answer (score 3):

See [`man git-add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add---force):

```
   -f, --force
       Allow adding otherwise ignored files.
```

So run this

```
git add --force vendor/test.txt
```

Comment: so i need to add 
git add --force vendor/test.txt
git commit -m ''
git push origin master
am i right  ?

Comment: Correct. Give this a try. You can always go back with 'git reset'

Comment: .gitignore doesn't care about pushing, it is used when adding files. If you manage to add a file or edit the .gitignore file to ignore an already added file, git still tracks that file just as it tracks any other file it tracks.

Answer (score 0):

In you .gitignore file

```
/vendor
!/vendor/test.txt
```

Comment: i already do that , when i checked git status then it will not showing test.txt

Comment: *It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.* [Documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)